# Import CSV File from Dynamic Path using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

File Path :

> 'D:\TEST\Sales Data-20Nov2017.csv

Table1

```
EMP     NAME    SALES Till Date     SALES 2015-16
A       Sam         50                  30
B       Bob         40                  60
C       Cat         30                  20
D       Doll        20                  50
E       Eric        10                  25
F       Fed         15                  10
```

How to Import csv file from Above path with dynamic date using SQL query?

Csv File contents above data

Kindly suggest SQL query using above path with dynamic Date

[image]

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ? Please choose one

Comment: `"How to Import csv file from Above path with dynamic date using SQL query?"` Do you know the dates or it is unknown ?

Comment: Its current date..will use Date on which code will execute